# Controls are not loaded for formatting/adding images on questions and answers

Tags: bug

The following situation passed yesterday, (*24/08/2022*), as today (*25/08/2022*), the described situation bellow is not ocurring

---

I found that in both Meta and Stack Overflow - while trying to post an answer, the controls for load images/links, etc, are not loaded.

[image: Highlighted error details in console]

*Screenshot showing the error and the section where the snippet controls are not loaded:*

[image: Screenshot]

These are the details found on the Console of the browser:

```
Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'speaker'.
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
edit:1176 Uncaught ReferenceError: gtag is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (edit:1176:30)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2:27449)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:28213)
    at e.<computed> [as resolve] (jquery.min.js:2:29192)
    at stub.en.js?v=fb1564797261:1:12177
    at Object.<anonymous> (stub.en.js?v=fb1564797261:1:17647)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2:27449)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:28213)
    at e.<computed> [as resolve] (jquery.min.js:2:29192)
    at Object.<anonymous> (stub.en.js?v=fb1564797261:1:17281)
```

At selecting the `edit:1176:30`, I get these lines where the error is hightlighted:

```
    var ga4Settings = {
        tracker: gtag, // <= Error is here.
        trackingCodes: [
            'G-WCZ03SZFCQ'
        ],
        consentsToPerformanceCookies: "denied",
        consentsToTargetingCookies: "denied"
                };
    
    StackExchange.ga.init({ GA3: ga3Settings, GA4: ga4Settings });
    
    StackExchange.ga.setDimension('dimension1', '17277451');
```

What could be the reason of this issue?

P.S: The formatting you are looking on this question is the ones I barely remember by making the formatting directly with characters - not even the shrotcuts works.

Comment: The canonical is *[JavaScript is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381510/)* (über meta).