# "You have started editing this post. Abandon the edit?" opens briefly and immediately closes if I hit Escape button

Tags: bug, edits, safari

I was trying to edit a question that I just asked, and I've found a bug where I can't use the Escape button. The dialog saying "You have started editing this post. Abandon the edit?" briefly flashes for a split second and disappears immediately without being able to click anything. This is happening both when I make a change to the title or the question.

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to a question. Doesn't matter if it's yours or someone else's (if you have access to editing others' questions)
- Hit edit.
- Make a change. Adding a single letter to either the title or the body is enough.
- Hit Escape button on keyboard.
- The "You have started editing this post. Abandon the edit?" dialog box appears briefly and disappears immediately without being able to hit okay or cancel.

I'm on Safari 15.6 on macOS 12.5

UPDATE: I've hard refreshed, logged out, restarted my Mac, emptied caches, still the same. No errors on JS console.

Comment: No repro on Chrome (just tested it), nor do I recall this happening a couple of hours ago on Firefox. Could be related to [the recent JavaScript breakage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420063/366904). Try a hard refresh and see if you can still reproduce?

Comment: No Repro on FF101 + Win10_PRO, both for 'Question' + 'Answer' (in 'Title' + 'Body'). 'Escape' does "nothing", except stopping the Cursor from flashing at the 2nd 'Escape'... // Mini-Nitpicking, you/the Error Dialog mention(s) "Post" (in the Title), but the Thread is only about 'Question', =>maybe you could check also if you also have the Issue when editing an 'Answer'...

Comment: The same would happen for a defunc Esc key (in some failure modes - one keypress registered ***as two***). Mechanical failures in switches are not uncommon. Can you rule this out by using an external USB keyboard or an external wireless keyboard? (What keyboard *are* you using?)

Comment: Does this occur on all subsequent post revision views or just the one where you have hit Esc? Also, does this prevent you from submitting the revision?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Perhaps they could try with an on-screen keyboard as well instead of potentially buying a second keyboard. I'm assuming MacOS has an on-screen keyboard option like Windows does.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I've enabled macOS Accesibility [on-screen] keyboard. If I press Esc there, it _sometimes_ happens. I've noticed the following (not 100% accurate, but generally occuring) pattern: if I click (press and immediately release, normal click) the same problem happens. However, if I press and _HOLD_ the esc with on screen keyboard, it stays in a loop of constant appearing/disappearing, and it can either stop at being dismissed or appeared state depending on when I release the on-screen keyboard. if I _hold_ the physical Esc, it _always_ ends on dismissed state though.

Comment: *"However, if I press and HOLD the esc with on screen keyboard, it stays in a loop of constant appearing/disappearing"* - this is pretty much normal, the same happens in Chrome. You hold a key down, it keeps triggering press events. I guess somewhere a check for the 'repeat' flag in the keyboard event needs to be added.